# Limiting a DateTime to 10 years before

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

I want to limit a result to only include records form between `Date.Now` all the way to 10 years ago.

How do I do this?

```
 strWhere = WhereAction_DueAfterDate(Date.Now - 10 years)
 strWhere &= " And" & WhereAction_DueBeforeDate(Date.Now)
```

Comment: where you want to apply the  limit

Comment: I edited the code a bit see if you understand now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AddYears` in `DateTime` class:

```
DateTime now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
strWhere = WhereAction_DueAfterDate(now.AddYears(-10))
strWhere &= " And" & WhereAction_DueBeforeDate(now)
```

It allows you to modify the `Now` `DateTime` back by putting `-` sign.

Side note: declare your `DateTime.Now` once before you process it further. This is just to avoid little time difference which might happen between the first call and the second call of `DateTime.Now` if we do otherwise:

```
strWhere = WhereAction_DueAfterDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10))
strWhere &= " And" & WhereAction_DueBeforeDate(DateTime.Now) 'There is a little difference between the first and the second DateTime Now
```

Comment: @AndreSmith great! :) simply declare the `DateTime.Now` once if you use it multiple times (see my updated answer). This is to avoid little time difference if you don't do so, but call `DateTime.Now` multiple times like in your original code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AddYears()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx) method to complete the operation.

```
strWhere = WhereAction_DueAfterDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10))
```

Hope that the requirement is for executing a query, if so you can use:

```
Datecolumn >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 YEAR) // for mysql
```